# play audio using AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient when device locked

Tags: ios, swift, audio, avaudioplayer

I am working on alarm app,my functionality requires audio should play when locked but should not play when its silent.
My app doesnt go in background because i have used Application does not run in background flag

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider using the UILocalNotification Class : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/

Basically you can schedule local notifications and set custom sounds, however keep in mind alert sounds have a maximum duration of 30 seconds and there is no way to repeat them automatically. (An app could schedule multiple local notifications in pre-defined time intervals to simulate a repeating alert)

Ref. link: http://oleb.net/blog/2014/02/alarm-clock-apps-ios/

Comment: notiications have been scheduled, i am facing problem in playing audio when device is silent and locked, i have to play when locked

Comment: But you said in the question that you want: "my functionality requires audio should play when locked but should not play when its silent." I don't see any reason why your local notifications are not working when your device is locked.

Comment: i am facing problem in playing audio, notification are working perfect.